# How to create a child of Player?

Tags: javascript, oop

```
var Game = function(){

    var game = this;

    game.Player = {
        pts:[]
    }

   }
```

for example in php it could be as:

```
game.Computer extends game.Player
```

But how can I do a child from game.Player in javascript in the same class?

`[update]` `[1]`

```
var Game = function(){

    var game = this;

    game.Player = {
        pts:[],
        test: function(){ alert('test'); }
    }

    Player.prototype = new Computer;

    game.Computer = {

    }
}

var game = new Game();

game.Computer.test();
```

I'm not sure @BenM

`[update]` `[2]`

or even like this:

```
var Game = function(){

    var game = this;

    game.Player = {
        pts:[],
        test: function(){ alert('test'); }
    }

    game.Player.prototype = game.Computer {

    }

}

var game = new Game();

game.Computer.test();
```

That is wrong too, can't extend it as is. Sorry if it's a lot of code here.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't include extended classes, since it's not truly an OO language. You could do something like this: `Player.prototype = new Computer`.

Comment: can I then get a Computer like this: `game.Computer`?

Comment: Assuming you have a `game.Computer` function, yes.

Comment: I'm updated the source as u said, not working :/

Comment: @BenM: It seems the OP rather wants it the other way round.

Comment: @AviAtion: Your `Player` object is not even a constructor function, so setting its `prototype` property makes no sense. What do you mean by "making Computer a child of Player" - why don't you make them instances of the same "class" (while [JavaScript has of course no classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572))?

Answer (score 0):

You really seem to be looking for a basic tutorial on how to do inheritance in JavaScript. Here's a good one: http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-inheritance-by-example/